# Configuration Manager does not exist in namespace

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-assembly

I am trying to call a connection string from  App.config in my Windows form application.

Here is the C# calling the connection string

```
var connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myTestString"].ConnectionString;
```

It has the red line under configuration manager saying that is does not exist, and that I should check the assembly; this is what the assembly ref looks like.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
```

Here is the app.config code, even though I do not think it is relevant.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>

    <add name="myConnectionString" connectionString="Data source=10.10.10.25;Initial Catalog=CRCIVR;uid=CRCIVR;password=wycoff;" />
    <add name="myTestString" connectionString="Data source=10.10.10.242;Initial Catalog=CRCIVR;User uid=TThomas;password=tthomas;" />

  </connectionStrings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

I am using visual studio 2012, so is there any reason you can see why System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager would not exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a reference to `System.Configuration`  in project references.

Comment: Why do I have to do this step for a form application, and not an ASP application? That would be very helpful knowledge! If you would be so kind to answer.

Comment: In asp.net you use WebConfigurationManager class. It is not the same. WebConfigurationManager lives in System.Web namespace.